# What are the per capita alcohol consumption rates of England from 1700 to 1900?

Tags: europe, england, britain, victorian, alcohol

The rates are readily available for the period 1800 onwards but there is some trouble finding equivalent data for the period prior to 1800. Moreover, the data that I have some across so far even for the period 1800-1850 is not very satisfactory.

For example, one may take a look at this which gives the rates for each decade from 1800 to 1930: https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm200910/cmselect/cmhealth/151/15106.htm - In this, the statistics appear to be confusing. The rates are given in gallons per capita with rates for wine and spirit enlarged. Moreover, since it is a graphical chart, one cannot easily deduce the exact number of alcohol consumed.

It'd be far more helpful if data was to be presented in a modern manner: that is, the rates be given in "litres of pure alcohol consumed per capita per year" in exact numbers.

I very well understand that there may be some problems getting such data for prior 1800, but surely it won't be that hard for the early and middle 19th century overall? I am well aware that such rates are readily available in a modern and exact form for the period 1890 in several European countries in: *"Holmes, A. J., & Anderson, K. (2017). Convergence in national alcohol consumption patterns: New global indicators. Journal of Wine Economics, 12(2), 117-148"*. It would be very great if rates for the period anywhere from 1700 to 1900 were to be given in a similar manner as to 1890 in the source above.

I request specifically for the rates be given, if possible, for each decade for the 18th and 19th century. Once again, it should be remembered that they be provided in litres per capita consumed per year.

Comment: When you say "_readily available in a modern and exact form_", I suspect that you don't fully understand the nature of the evidence that underlies the data presented by Holmes & Anderson. For example, the methodology and various data sources used in one of the sources they cite is explained in [Annual Database of Global Wine Markets, 1835 to 2016: Methodology, Derived Indicators and Sources](https://www.adelaide.edu.au/wine-econ/pubs/working_papers/WP0417.pdf), which might give you some idea of just how hard compiling that data really is.